# SQL Server 2008 view error with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

I cant figure out why this code executes as a query but when I execute it in a view it throws a the multi-part identifier could not be bound, error.

When I take out the case statement It works in the view, so I believe it is something that has to do with the case statement.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
WITH [cteFrostSum] AS
(
    SELECT ID AS ID, theMonth  as Mo,
    SUM(dbo.Frost.[DRAmount])  AS [DRAmount]
    FROM dbo.Frost 
    GROUP BY [ID], theMonth
) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TOP (100) PERCENT      
    dbo.ternean.MemberID, 
    dbo.ternean.SSN, 
    dbo.ternean.GroupName, 
    dbo.ternean.CustomerID, 
    dbo.ternean.GroupNumber, 
    dbo.ternean.LastName, 
    dbo.Frost.DRAmount, 
    dbo.Frost.HittheBank, 
    dbo.Frost.MonthofPremium, 
    cte.[DRAmount] AS [SUM_Frost_Balance],
    dbo.ternean.TotalCost,
    cte.[DRAmount] - dbo.ternean.TotalCost AS Diff,
    dbo.ternean.ACH_RoutingNo, 
    dbo.Frost.RTNum, 
    dbo.ternean.ACH_AcctNo,
    dbo.Frost.AccountNumber, 

    CASE
        WHEN dbo.Frost.RTNum <> SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_RoutingNo, 2, 20)
            THEN 'DO not match'
        WHEN dbo.Frost.RTNum = SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_RoutingNo, 2, 20)
            THEN 'match'
    END AS [Routing # match], 
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_AcctNo, 2, 20) <> dbo.Frost.AccountNumber
            THEN 'DO not match'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_AcctNo, 2, 20) = dbo.Frost.AccountNumber
            THEN 'match'
    END AS [Account # match],
    dbo.Frost.theMonth
FROM dbo.Frost
INNER JOIN dbo.ternean ON dbo.Frost.ID = dbo.ternean.CustomerID
    AND dbo.Frost.theMonth = dbo.ternean.theMonth 
INNER JOIN [cteFrostSum] cte ON dbo.Frost.ID = cte.ID
    AND dbo.Frost.theMonth = cte.Mo
ORDER BY dbo.ternean.theMonth
```

Comment: Which multipart identifier cannot be bound?

Comment: Are ALL values of ACH_RoutingNo and ACH_acctNo at LEAST 21 characters in length?

Comment: In other words does: Select ACH_RoutingNo, ACH_AcctNo from dbo.ternean T where len(T.ACH_RoutingNo) < 21 OR len (T.ACH_AcctNo) < 21 return or isnull(T.ACH_routingNo) or is null(T.ACH_AcctNo) return any records?

Comment: This is the Identifier. the multi-part identifier "dbo.Frost.RTNum" could not be bound.
the multi-part identifier "dbo.Frost.RTNum" could not be bound.
the multi-part identifier "dbo.Frost.AccountNumber" could not be bound.
the multi-part identifier "dbo.Frost.AccountNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: No the values of ACH_RoutingNo and ACH_acctNo are not 21 characters but they may be in the future.

Comment: I took out the substring function and I still get the same error.

Comment: `TOP (100) PERCENT ... ORDER BY ` is nonsensical in a view. See [TOP 100 Percent ORDER BY Considered Harmful.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/24/560396.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate your error but couldn't.

Why are you using multi-part identifiers the field names anyway? The list of fields in the select statement can only refer to the tables in the from clause, at first reading this query seems to be referring to the tables directly in the dbo schema.

Give your tables some nice easy aliases i.e.

```
FROM dbo.Frost AS F
```

and use them like this

```
F.RTNum
```

Secondly you can simplify your case statements and only do one test i.e.:

```
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(T.ACH_AcctNo, 2, 20) <> F.AccountNumber
    THEN 'DO not match'
    ELSE 'match'
END AS [Account # match]
```